# how to generate regional language pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

i generated English language html to PDF using html to PDF php script .but coming to regional language its showing string error.i am using utf-8 only.is there any onther script for regional language

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of encoding for different regional languages. The Internet says it is pretty hard to detect the encoding for any given document. Your best bet looks like trusting Firefox to tell you which encoding to use. I found [this](http://codeftw.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html) upon [searching](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20find%20out%20encoding%20of%20a%20language&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=2c234cd90c8a9f5c&bpcl=39650382&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.bmk&biw=1920&bih=955).